# How to multiple each object of several lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have three list and I want to multiply their objects in the order they appear in the list and then return the results in a new list:

```
a = [1,5,4,3]
b = [20, 44, 40, 100]
c = [222, 432, 670, 190]
```

The new list should have the results of these calculations:

```
new_list = [(1*20*222),(5*44*432), (4*40*670), (3*100*190)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new_list = [x * y * z for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Alternatively, especially usefuly if you have more than three lists:

```
import operator
new_list = [reduce(operator.mul, lst, 1) for lst in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Comment: This is what I like about python, no [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), just one or maybe 2 proper ways of solving a problem!

Answer (score 3):

```
[x * y * z for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]
```

iterates over a "zipped" list and multiplies their components.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: a = [1,5,4,3]

In [2]: b = [20, 44, 40, 100]

In [3]: c = [222, 432, 670, 190]

In [5]: [(x*y*z) for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c)]
Out[5]: [4440, 95040, 107200, 57000]
```